# PHP: Change Date format d/m/Y h:i:s a to m/d/Y h:i:s a

Tags: php

Example Dates:

```
31/10/2019 7:15 am
31/10/2019 11:58 am
```

**Output:**

```
01-01-1970 08:00:00 am
01-01-1970 08:00:00 am
```

I'm trying to change the date format on my database.
I've already try **date("d-m-Y h:i:s a", strtotime("31/10/2019 7:15 am"))** but it shows the output above.

Please help.

Comment: You must be using datetime data type i recommend you to use timestamp instead of datetime so when you will fetching the data back you can easily change the format according to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse the original date, and then format it in the way you want using `format`.

```php
function reformatDate ($dateStr) {
  return DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i a', $dateStr)->format('m/d/Y h:i:s a');
}

echo reformatDate('31/10/2019 7:15 am') . "\n"; // 10/31/2019 07:15:00 am
echo reformatDate('31/10/2019 11:58 am') . "\n"; // 10/31/2019 11:58:00 am
```

Comment: Hi Good Sir. I've try your solution and I have an error: "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare reformatDate() (previously declared in"

I've try to put the reformatedate in a variable but still the error shows up.

Comment: Hi Sir. I've already resolve the problem. The function form is in the while loop so the error shows up. Thank you for your resolution.